# Incorrect syntax for anonymous function

Tags: scala

I need help trying to get my anonymous function to compile in Scala.

See below:

```
private def mapBlock(helper: Helper): (Any) => Block = {
    (original: Any) => {
      val block = original.asInstanceOf[Block]
      // logic with helper here
      return block
    }
  }
```

However, when I compile this I get "Expression of type block does not conform to expected"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `return block` which is the returning to the `mapBlock` function the value `block`. But your `mapBlock` expectes a function typed `(Any) => Block`. To solve this just remove the `return` and have `block`.

```
private def mapBlock(helper: Helper): (Any) => Block = {
  (original: Any) => {
    val block = original.asInstanceOf[Block]
    // logic with helper here
    block
  }
}
```

If you want to have a `return` then you could name your function and return that. Although in Scala we generally omit all `return`s, so this would not be idiomatic Scala:

```
private def mapBlock(helper: Helper): (Any) => Block = {
  val function = (original: Any) => {
    val block = original.asInstanceOf[Block]
    // logic with helper here
    block
  }
  return function
}
```